# Get input value in Scrapy

Tags: input, web-crawler, scrapy

I have a rating with star in my web page that work with input ([see this page][1])

Now, I want to crawl value of input with Scrapy crawler, please help me.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What have you tried? Are you familiar with xpaths?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This one should give you right direction:

```
response.xpath('//input[contains(@class,'rating')]/@value')
```